# Countable-Dense Subset inside a Dense Set in R^n

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a problem where I need to pass from a dense set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $A$, to a countable dense set $B$ that is contained in $A$. I believe it should be true but am finding it hard to prove it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable basis given by open balls with rational centers and rational radii. For each open ball $C$ in the basis there is an element $a \in A$ such that $a \in C$ (since $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$). If we assign one element of $A$ to each basis element, we obtain a countable set $B \subset A$. Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains a basis element, so every open set contains an element of $B$. This shows that $B$ is dense.